# Vue.js select image if one exists

Tags: vue.js

I work with multiple companies that all utilize the same portals and webpages, I am trying to set the home icon to be their company logo IF they have provided one and set it to be a default mdi-home if they haven't. The logged in company is held in the company variable and I am trying to avoid using massive IF statements like `if company === 'company_1' OR company === 'company_2' OR ... load image else load mdi-home` but rather use something more similar to a try-catch statement so when future customers onboard, this wont need to change. (`try: customer_image catch: mdi_icom`)

Does anyone know of a way to handle this in vue.js ? Thanks for your help in advance

I've tried generic try and catch statements already but the images never raise an error even if the src does not exist, it just does not display anything and results in just no image rather than an mdi_icon

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try ternary: companyLogo ? 'logo-image-url' : 'mdi-home'